# Force margins on Google AdSense units in mobile view

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, adsense, margins

I have the following rules in my mobile CSS:

```
html{
    padding:15px;
}

body{
    margin:15px;
  }
```

All elements on the page obey these rules except Google's AdSense units.  These ads are in "auto" mode, which means you place one line of javascript in the `<head>` section of your HTML, and Google's algorithms choose the sizing and placement of the ad units.

All ad units display across the entire width of the viewport instead of respecting margins.  How do I force margins on them?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhUel.png]

Comment: don't know what you have in the HTML, but assuming you have a container div - have you tried applying margins to that instead? body/html are probably being overridden by adsense's own requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Adsense's auto-sized ads seems to override page's css.
The one thing you can try is to set a margin to your ad unit:

```css
.adsbygoogle{
  margin:10px !important;
}
```

But it can shake your page display in mobile devices. I recommend you to not use auto-sized ads in mobile if you want to set it's size boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my settings. Works fine both for desktop and mobile. Setting only "margin" causes problems in mobile (from left and right).

```
.adsbygoogle {
  margin-top:20px !important;
  margin-bottom:20px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `data-full-width-responsive="false"` parameter as described [here](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9183460).